# Split a bullet in 3 different directions using Quaternion.AngleAxis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to assign a skill to a projectile that, when used, divides the project into 3 (the original projectile and 2 more new ones).

However, when I instantiate these two clones, they keep following the same trajectory. The idea would be for them to take [this route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoA0E.png):

The green dotted curve indicating the motion of the original bullet, the blue vector indicating the instantaneous velocity of the original bullet at time of special activation, the red vectors indicating the two velocity vectors belonging to each of the newly spawned bullets, and the green angle indicating the direction of the new bullet relative to the original velocity direction

But at the moment, they spawn and continue following the same trajectory as the original. The sprites even rotate to the right angle, but that doesn't seem to make much difference in how the physics is applied.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

This is my code so far

Ability Script:

```
    public class AirSpecialSplit : MonoBehaviour, IAirSpecial
    {
        public float SplitAngleInDegrees = 10;
    
        GameObject bird_down;
        GameObject bird_up;
    
    
        public void ExecuteAirSpecial()
        {
            {
                //hold the velocity of the original bird
                Vector2 original_velocity = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
    
                //clone two new birds
 

                bird_down = Birb.MakeBirbCopy(this.gameObject);
                bird_up = Birb.MakeBirbCopy(this.gameObject);

                //apply the angle to the clones
                bird_down.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-SplitAngleInDegrees, Vector2.up);
                bird_up.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(SplitAngleInDegrees, Vector2.up);
    
                //get the rigidboy from the clones
                Rigidbody2D rb_bird_down = bird_down.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                Rigidbody2D rb_bird_up = bird_up.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                rb_bird_down.simulated = true;
                rb_bird_up.simulated = true;
    
 
                rb_bird_down.velocity = new Vector2(original_velocity.x, original_velocity.y);
                rb_bird_up.velocity = new Vector2(original_velocity.x, original_velocity.y);
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're just assigning the original velocity as the velocity of the new objects, but maybe you're aware of that and are asking what to do instead (?). Also, are the new objects children of the original object in the scene hierarchy? Or are they independent objects?

Comment: Yes, I imagine that this may be the cause of their _"just follow the original"_ problem, but any other solution I tried, results in the bullets just falling straight to the ground.
And yes, they are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Well you apply the same `velocity` to both so of course they will move in the same direction. The `velocity` is in world space!

You probably wanted to rather add the rotation like e.g.

```
rb_bird_down.velocity = bird_down.transform.forward * original_velocity.magnitude;
```

And before that you probably should take the current bullet rotation into account like

```
bird_down.tranform.rotation = transform.rotstion * Quaternion.Euler(0,0, -SplitAngleInDegrees);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. With these modifications, the birds did not even follow the trajectory of the parabola. They only fall in a straight line after being instantiated.

Comment: @Zimzom: Can you post the code for Birb.MakeBirbCopy()?

Comment: @scg sure  

`public static GameObject MakeBirbCopy( GameObject original )
    {
        Birb newBirb = Instantiate(original).GetComponent<Birb>();
        newBirb.m_canExecuteAirSpecial = false;
        return newBirb.gameObject;
    }`

Comment: Are the rigid bodies kinematic? (I'm guessing not, since you're manipulating the velocity.) Are there any other forces being applied, like gravity?

Comment: No, they are not Kinematic. I'm using gravity to calculate the parabola of the trajectory of the bullets

Comment: You might double-check to make sure the objects aren't colliding with each other. (It doesn't sound like that's what happening, so maybe you already have those interactions filtered out in Unity.) Also, if manipulating the velocity directly isn't producing the desired results due to some sort of interference with the physics system, you could instead apply lateral impulses to the new objects to get a similar effect. You probably wouldn't be able to get the precise 10 degrees you're using now, but maybe the result would be more in keeping with the physics-based approach.